# how to find all values satisfing a function whose depends on another function?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How can I find all values $x>0$ such that $\int_0^x [t]^2 \, \mathrm{d}t=2(x-1)$?

Does there exist an analytic solution to this problem? I mean a non iterative method to find these values, where $[t]$ is the function such that the value at $t$ is equal to the greatest integer smaller than $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint on how to compute this integral:

Write $x$ (I assume $x>0$) as $[x]+\{x\}$ and now $$\int_0^x=\int_0^1+\dots+\int_{[x]-1}^{[x]}+\int_{[x]}^{x}$$

Observe that on each interval $[k,k+1)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, you have $[t]^2=k^2$.